# Identity Map Pattern Real World Examples in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am struggling to get Identity Map Pattern real life (industry implementations) examples in Java.

I have been studying the Identity Map Pattern of the **Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture** book.

I understood the usage and applicability of this pattern but I haven't found any real-world examples.

Can you provide any practical examples of this design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters : [here](https://dzone.com/articles/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns) is a nice article on a real life example for the Identity Map Pattern.

An additional significant treat: [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7de2/0692c774798016e06d2eb0ade959c61df350.pdf) is a link to the **Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture** (by Martin Fowler!) mentioned above.

As for an actual example here : I view this pattern (and so do several other sources I have read) as similar in spirit to lazy initialization.

The basic and recurring concept is : you have a heavy weight object which you wish to retrieve (generally a DB entity, but there is no reason to be limited just to DBs), and you use a map in order to store a new instance of this object if it does not already exist in the Map.

So keeping that in mind (and this is quick and dirty, without proper generics, etc..):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

interface HeavyWeightInterface {
    public String myToString();
}

class ConcreteHeavyWeight implements HeavyWeightInterface {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS = 100000;
    // non DB heavy class
    private String base;
    private List<String> dummyObjects;

    public ConcreteHeavyWeight(String keyBase) {
        this.base = keyBase;
        this.dummyObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS).forEach(
           nbr -> { 
               dummyObjects.add(base + " : " + nbr);
           });
    }

    public String myToString() {
        return "My base is : " + base + " with an internal DS of " + dummyObjects.size() + " entities";
    }
}

interface HeavyWeightFactory {
    public HeavyWeightInterface build(String key);
}

class ConcreteHeavyWeightFactory implements HeavyWeightFactory{
    public HeavyWeightInterface build(String key) {
        return new ConcreteHeavyWeight(key);
    }
}

class IdentityMap {

    private Map<String,HeavyWeightInterface> internalMap;
    private HeavyWeightFactory hwfactory;
    public IdentityMap(HeavyWeightFactory hwfactory) {
        this.internalMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.hwfactory = hwfactory;
    }
    public HeavyWeightInterface retreive(String key) {
        if(!internalMap.containsKey(key)) {
            internalMap.put(key,hwfactory.build(key));
        }
        return internalMap.get(key);
    }

}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        IdentityMap im = new IdentityMap(new ConcreteHeavyWeightFactory());
        HeavyWeightInterface hw0 = im.retreive("Test0");
        im.retreive("Test1");
        im.retreive("Test2");
        im.retreive("Test3");
        HeavyWeightInterface hw1 = im.retreive("Test0");
        System.out.println("First call with Test0 key = " + hw0 + ", Second call with Test0 key = " + hw1);
        System.out.println(hw1.myToString());
    }
}
```

And the output is :

```
First call with Test0 key = ConcreteHeavyWeight@224aed64, Second call with Test0 key = ConcreteHeavyWeight@224aed64
My base is : Test0 with an internal DS of 100000 entities
```

Answer (score 1):

JPA persistence context is a good example of the Identity Map Pattern.
In JPA entity identity is maintained within a transaction and within an entity manager. For example:

```
Employee employee1 = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 123);
Employee employee2 = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 123);
assert (employee1 == employee2);
```

Assert expression will return true. The second call will get the entity from the persistence context, without querying the database.

From the [EntityManager javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html):

> A persistence context is a set of entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance. Within the persistence context, the entity instances and their lifecycle are managed. The EntityManager API is used to create and remove persistent entity instances, to find entities by their primary key, and to query over entities.

See also [JPA wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching#Object_Identity) object identity explanation.